# Converting between 12 hour and 24 hour clock with i18n in ember.js

Tags: ember.js, internationalization, ember-i18n

I wondered if there is a way to convert between a 12-hour and 24-hour clock using i18n and ember.js?

I18n does have the DATE-object with meridians described under. But I'm not sure if conversion between 24-hour and 12-hour times are supported.

`var DATE = {
     day_names: ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"],
     abbr_day_names: ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"], 
     month_names: [null, "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"], 
     abbr_month_names: [null, "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"], 
meridian: ["AM", "PM"]
  };`

I allready use i18n for the translation part of the internationalization of my site. So it would be nice to not need an additional library for times.

Comment: If you're using https://github.com/jamesarosen/ember-i18n, it looks like it isn't, you should submit a PR.

Comment: I'm currently using the i18n.js-script from github.com/fnando/i18n-js and have added the helper to make the handlebars myself.

Comment: I've started created a jsbin, but gotta run, I'm dropping it here for historical http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wuzehaha/1/edit

Comment: Since you've added I18n tag, I have to ask. What do you mean by "converting 12/24 hour clock"? Do you want to simply display a time according to a Locale? That's time formatting, there is no need to convert anything. Or do you want to parse user input?

Comment: I simply mean time formatting. So pretty much whether you display 20:42 or 8:42 PM. I just wondered if this was sometjing i18n-js could do, but I guess you would have to configure it yourself just as you do with regular translations.

Comment: @kingpin2k This seem to be somewhat close to what I need. Thanks :) Although it seem I must add the delimiters, rules and translations for all date elements for every language I want to support. But that should not be too difficult. Also the rule on whether to choose 24-hour or 12-hour clock based on locale would have been nice. I will take a look on creating it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving the simplified problem of choosing between 12 and 24 hour time using separate handlebars dates with I18n.l. Then I specified that format so the date objects would get formatted in that way in the translations.js

For English locale etc. I use the 12-hour clock

```
time: {
    formats: {
        short: '%-I:%M %p', // hh:mm tt
    },
}
```

For Norwegian, Swedish locale ect. I use the 24-hour clock

```
time: {
    formats: {
         short: '%-H:%M', // hh:mm
    }
}
```

For languages with different delimiters and meridians and names for weekdays ect. you must also specify those and not use the default DATE object that is given in the i18n.js file.

The accepted formats in standard i18n-js are:

- %a - The abbreviated weekday name (Sun)
- %A  - The full weekday name
  (Sunday) %b  - The abbreviated month name (Jan)
- %B  - The full month name (January)
- %c  - The preferred local date and time representation
- %d  - Day of the month (01..31) %-d - Day of the month (1..31)
- %H  - Hour of the day, 24-hour clock (00..23)
- %-H - Hour of the day, 24-hour clock (0..23)
- %I  - Hour of the day, 12-hour clock (01..12)
- %-I - Hour of the day, 12-hour clock (1..12)
- %m  - Month of the year (01..12)
- %-m - Month of the year (1..12)
- %M - Minute of the hour (00..59)
- %-M - Minute of the hour (0..59)
- %p  - Meridian indicator (AM  or  PM)
- %S  - Second of the minute (00..60)
- %-S - Second of the minute (0..60)
- %w  - Day of the week (Sunday is 0, 0..6)
- %y  - Year without a century (00..99)
- %-y - Year without a century (0..99)
- %Y  - Year with century
- %z  - Timezone offset (+0545)